# Have trouble when using heredoc syntax in PHP

Tags: php, heredoc

```
<?php
        $output = <<< END 
        <table style="display: table;" class="listview rowstyle-rowhighlight" id="resourcegrid">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="70"></th>
              <th style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="sortable fd-column-0"><a class="fdTableSortTrigger" href="#">Name</a></th>
              <th style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="sortable fd-column-1"><a class="fdTableSortTrigger" href="#">Contributor</a></th>
              <th style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="sortable fd-column-3"><a class="fdTableSortTrigger" href="#">Modified</a></th>
            </tr>
          </thead><tbody>
END;

echo $output;
```

When I run it reports :

```
Parse error: parse error on line 2
```

But I don't see anything abnormal.

Comment: Is the END token actually in column 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you should use `$output = <<<END` instead of `$output = <<< END` (Note the lack of space)

```
echo <<<END
heredoc string...
END;
```

Make sure that there is no space before or after the `END` even a single extraneous space could cause problems. Looking at the code you posted, you seem to have a space before and after the `END`.

From the [php website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> Warning
>
> It is very important to note that the
>   line with the closing identifier must
>   contain no other characters, except
>   possibly a semicolon (;). That means
>   especially that the identifier may not
>   be indented, and there may not be any
>   spaces or tabs before or after the
>   semicolon. It's also important to
>   realize that the first character
>   before the closing identifier must be
>   a newline as defined by the local
>   operating system. This is \n on UNIX
>   systems, including Mac OS X. The
>   closing delimiter (possibly followed
>   by a semicolon) must also be followed
>   by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing
>   identifier is not "clean", it will not
>   be considered a closing identifier,
>   and PHP will continue looking for one.
>   If a proper closing identifier is not
>   found before the end of the current
>   file, a parse error will result at the
>   last line.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `<<<END` (without space).

Example:

```
<?php
    echo <<<END
Heredoc string.
END;
```

Comment: @wamp http://codepad.viper-7.com/TazuD9

Answer (score 2):

Using the following on my localhost outputs no errors.

```
<?php
        $output = <<<END
        <table style="display: table;" class="listview rowstyle-rowhighlight" id="resourcegrid">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="70"></th>
              <th style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="sortable fd-column-0"><a class="fdTableSortTrigger" href="#">Name</a></th>
              <th style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="sortable fd-column-1"><a class="fdTableSortTrigger" href="#">Contributor</a></th>
              <th style="-moz-user-select: none;" class="sortable fd-column-3"><a class="fdTableSortTrigger" href="#">Modified</a></th>
            </tr>
          </thead><tbody>
END;
```

Like others mentioned, I simply got rid of the space.